Function to ensure your value is wrapped in a Maybe
I'd like a function that takes an argument and gives back a Maybe value. If the argument has type Maybe a, the implementation should be id, and if the argument is anything else, the implementation should be Just. Surely the right way to do this is with a typeclass, but I'm struggling to get it right. Any suggestions?
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ toMaybe 3         -- should be `Just 3`
    print $ toMaybe (Just 3)  -- should be `Just 3` also

I feel like this is probably trivial if I know the right language pragmas or something, but I don't.

Related reading: 1 2. Related by the solution: you'll need to make a new class, and then write instances for all the existing types like (), Char, Int, etc.

The part I'm struggling the most with is that the type signature of toMaybe depends on the instance type. I can't just do class ToMaybe a; toMaybe :: a -> Maybe a because toMaybe has the wrong signature when a is already a Maybe b. and I can't do class ToMaybe a b; toMaybe :: a -> Maybe b because the compiler can't figure out any constraints on b. I'd be happy to write instances for lots of types if I could figure out the right class.

You'll need TypeFamilies, and will probably want DerivingVia+StandaloneDeriving+UndecidableInstances.
class Wrap a where
    type Wrapped a
    wrap :: a -> Wrapped a

instance Wrap (Maybe a) where
    type Wrapped (Maybe a) = Maybe a
    wrap = id

-- choice 1: only TypeFamilies
instance Wrap Int where
    type Wrapped Int = Maybe Int
    wrap = Just

instance Wrap Bool where
    type Wrapped Bool = Maybe Bool
    wrap = Just

instance Wrapped () where
    type Wrapped () = Maybe ()
    wrap = Just

-- etc. etc.

-- choice 2: we love extensions, turn them all on why not
newtype UseJust a = UseJust a
instance Wrap (UseJust a) where
    type Wrapped (UseJust a) = Maybe a
    wrap (UseJust a) = Just a

deriving via UseJust Int instance Wrap Int
deriving via UseJust Bool instance Wrap Bool
deriving via UseJust () instance Wrap ()
-- etc. etc.

And I'll just add a slight warning: to me, this smells. Are you sure you aren't just looking for the Monad (well, Functor) instance for Maybe? If not, are you double-plus sure that two layers of Maybe really isn't conceptually the right thing to return when presented with a single layer of Maybe?

The insight I needed was that the return type should be defined within the instance. Thanks so much!

re: the smell. The real thing I'm trying to do is to ensure that my types are inside a State StdGen rather than a Maybe, and the types are usually functions whose eventual value always has the same type (e.g., Int -> Foo or Bool -> String -> Foo). I got annoyed that I keep wanting to have two versions of various functions, one for when it's already in a State StdGen and another that is just firstFunction . return, and my hope is that I can get one set of functions that works in both situations.

@Alan I certainly get the desire for visual symmetry by just using the same function name everywhere (even though it's resolving to a different function via the typeclass). But the type checker will still have to be able to tell whether you're already in State StdGen or not, so the only thing it gets you semantically is the ability for the human reader/writer to be confused about which situation applies; that's the "smell", really. Sometimes you're better off just actually writing the . pure and being explicit. But visual symmetry is nice, too.

Another way to phrase that objection is that classes should be used for abstraction. If it doesn't make sense to write code which works uniformly over all instances of a class it probably shouldn't be a class.
